# sub nav is not sliding down correctly

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to create an instant search using jQuery and ajax .and somehow it's working fine but I used a sub nav to display the results. The problem is that the subnav is sliding down but its getting disappear when it shouldn't.

**Html**

```
<ul>
<li>
<form>

  <input type="text" id="keyword">

</form>
<ul class="subnav">

</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**jquery:-**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        if ($(this).val().length != "") {

            $('.submenu').slideDown()

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",

                url: "test.php",

                data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),

                success: function(data) {

                    $('.submenu').html(data);

                } else {

                    $('.submenu').slideUp()
                }

            })
        });
```

css: 
    .submenu     {
    width:165px;
    background:#F30;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    }

when I mention height in the css it works fine but without height its not working ..and sorry for not organising the code .it is hard for me to do that on phone ..

thanks in advanced

Comment: can you add all css js and html to a fiddle please

Comment: You do not have an if statement in the success callback. This may cause an error. You should probably include `if (data) {` before `$('.submenu').html(data);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your "else" is used incorrectly.

Remove the "else" part, and do something to this affect;

```
       //$('.submenu').slideUp();

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: "test.php",

            data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),

            success: function(data) {
                $('.submenu').slideDown();
                $('.submenu').html(data);

            }

        })
```

I commented out the top line, as you may want to use it to hide the subnav while results are being found (you may also want to have it slideUp() as well if the overall if function is false, so adding an else to the main if function).

Comment: The jsfiddle will fail because there is no JQuery lib included, and the test5.php file will not exist in JS fiddle, so the ajax will never be successful.

Did you try the suggestions I advised above?

Comment: Yeah I have tried your suggestion but results was same.and jsfiddle sorry cant do it on phone .by the way just so you know that its working absolutely fine when I have the height set of subnav but without height its not working ..using your suggestion too

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Can't you just set the height? As surely you don't want the subnav to be so long it goes off the page. Maybe try setting height:auto; but applying a max-height value as well?

Comment: I have tried using the height:auto but subnav wouldn't stay visible but when I set height:200px or etc the subnav stays visible as long as there is a value insides the input box